# How to change template directory in puppet

Tags: puppet

My default template directory is

```
# sudo puppet config print templatedir
/var/lib/puppet/templates
```

While my modulepath is

```
# sudo puppet config print modulepath --section master
/etc/puppet/modules:/usr/share/puppet/modules
```

How do I make template directory relative to module path?
i.e. something like `/etc/puppet/modules/module_name/template`

P.S. I googled it, did not find relevant result. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `template` function to return a string using your modulepath https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#template. If you wanted to reference a template in `/etc/puppet/modules/module_name/templates`, then you could do `template(module_name/template.erb)`. If you wanted to use an `.epp` template instead of `.erb`, then you can use the `epp` function https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/function.html#epp.

Since the `content` attribute (https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-content) of the the `file` resource accepts strings, you can use the string return value of these two functions in your `file` resources like so:

```
file { '/path/to/file':
  ensure  => file,
  content => template('module_name/template.erb'),
}

file { '/path/to/file':
  ensure  => file,
  content => epp('module_name/template.epp'),
}
```

Comment: I was doing same thing. It says template not found when I use `template(module_name/template.erb)`. It works file if I simply use `template(template.erb)` and place the file in template dir.

Comment: @AtmeshMishra Did you put it in a `templates` directory or a `template` directory? I don't know if you made a typo above or are putting it in the wrong directory.

Comment: `|-- manifests
|   |-- configuration.pp
|   |-- init.pp
|   |-- server.pp
|   -- params.pp
|-- metadata.json
|-- Rakefile
|-- README.md
|-- spec
|   |-- spec_helper.rb
|    -- spec.opts
|-- template
|    -- file.conf.erb`

Comment: @AtmeshMishra Ok then you made a typo in the directory name. Follow the instructions in my answer and it will work for you.